# What to do if I cannot finish all open tasks on time

Tags: project-management, deadlines

As project manager, I have many open tasks that I realized I cannot finish them by deadline.what is the best approach? should I ;
Finish all tasks at each 80% or finish few of them at 100% ?
I am not talking in SCRUM scope where I have to re-estimate the tasks and put them back to the product log for the next Sprint, but I am talking in a regular context where my team receives tickets with deadline from other departments.

Thank you

Comment: at what point do you realise this? Seems like something you should recognise when it arises not when dead line is looming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should speak with your stakeholder and ask them to prioritise. Some tasks are going to fail, and some tasks are more important than others. The stakeholder can (or should be able to) make that distinction, and it's their call.

The best time to have this conversation is, of course, when you first realize there might be a problem, not at the very end. This is true for all levels of management, from the front-line worker all the way up to you. If other people report to you, make sure they understand that it's important to know when something is likely to miss the deadline, so you can re-prioritise.

Many people think that missing deadlines equals failure. This is true only when you have no time to adjust your workload. As Uncle Bob [once said](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/04/20/Why-Is-Estimating-So-Hard.html), the only way to truly estimate something is to actually do it. Insist on early progress feedback, not that you can blame someone, but so that you won't have to.

Comment: They might also be able to change the task, or push parts until later, or move deadlines. These aren't ideal, but the issue owner (stakeholder) will know more about how to address issues.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is speak up as ***early as possible***.

That's all there is.

Immediately walk over to the party in question and say "Looks like we won't be able to get that list done, give me your thoughts on X Y Z ..."

(The first thing they will say is "Why didn't you tell us sooner?" But that's life.)